# Round brown spots on living room walls?

Tags: walls, stain

We moved in just shy of a year ago. In the past month these spots have been showing up- they are dry to the touch and only in our living room - on both the interior and exterior walls.

For reference the home was built in ‘92. THOUGHTS? Thanks so much!

[image]

Comment: what is the scale? Did you repaint after moving in?

Comment: Are the spots in rows , like moisture causing screws or nails to rust? I am guessing at rusty fasteners because I can’t tell the scale had have seen this. If this is the case a schlack type of primer may be needed and repaint to keep the rust from bleeding through.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. We'll need more information before we can help you. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: What material are the walls made out of?  This also looks like a wood knot bleeding through the paint.

Comment: Did you ever find the cause? With no additional info we can’t provide much help and we really like to help those that ask. If you have found a solution it could help others if you post it as an answer and accept it.